# When should I use "convention tag" in EL&U?

Tags: support, tags

I searched the convention tag, but the top google [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=convention+tag+english+stack+exchange&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new) says, **"the convention tag has no usage guidance."**

I have no idea which sense does this tag relate to. When should I use this tag?

Comment: It may have arisen as an attempt to describe various formal or informal guidelines such as punctuation rules and other shared approaches to handling style decisions consistently. Questions of these types tend to be bundled under the tag "writing-style," although that tag name is certainly at least as susceptible to misconstruction and multiple interpretations as "convention" is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The *X* tag has no usage guidance" means that the tag has no tag wiki/excerpt. You can see the full wiki by clicking on a tag, then clicking on "Learn more...", which in your case should take you to [this page](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/convention/info).

It looks to me like this tag is used on questions that have next to nothing in common. "The way things are done" isn't a particularly descriptive category. In other words, it doesn't look like a good tag, so my advice is to *not* use it. In fact, it could probably be burninated, if enough people care to edit.